# Python xml install not working

Tags: xml, python-3.x, pip

When i try 'import xml' in IDE is get the error missing module. When i use 'pip list' in command prompt xml is missing from my pip installs list. When i try a fresh install i get the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image: python setup.py egg_info failed error code 1]

I have installed ez-setup and upgraded setuptools through pip and pip is up to date (version 10.0.1).

Answer (score 2):

[xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) is a module from stdlib so `import xml` must always succeed. If it doesn't you have a rather broken Python installation. Also `pip list` never lists stdlib modules, it only lists modules managed by `pip`.

[py-xml](https://pypi.org/project/py-xml/) works only with Python 2, not 3. The code `open('README.md', 'r', 'utf-8')` is a complete mess, it works with neither Python 2 nor 3.

If you're not satisfied with standard `xml` I recommend to install [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had another `xml.py` in my working directory. So, I renamed it. Now, it's working